# Can someone ID this moth seen in Bellandur, Bangalore?

Tags: species-identification, lepidoptera

[image: military-moth]

Picture taken near Saul Kere. You may need to zoom in.

Answer (score 2):

It's the Indian Lily Moth 
(https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytela_gloriosae).
[image: picture from wikipedia]

Comment: That looks like a plausible ID. The site generally prefers the key details of the answer to be contained in the answer itself, not just at the link. What are the distinguishing features of the Indian Lily Moth, and how would you tell it apart from similar moths?